# What should I do to ensure that multiple OSs installed on a computer work together?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, multi-boot

If I have multiple OSs installed on a single computer (e.g. Windows 10, Mac OS X El Capitan, and Arch Linux), what can I do to make these OSs work together better? Is it possible to synchronize certain folders (e.g. so that the downloads folder on OSX is the same as the one on Windows)? What other things would you recommend doing to the system?

Answer (score 0):

Read Wikipedia about `BIOS`, `UEFI`, `BOOT`. Decide which physical disk you will boot from, MBR/GPT, which boot manager you will use, and how you can get the "other" systems to 1) leave the boot setup alone (don't overwrite it with the "right" way); and 2) allow themselves to be booted by your boot manager.

Consider running the "others" in Virtual Machines, if your hardware supports it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you're hardware will support all of your devices. Sometimes proper drivers can be hard to find.
2. I'd have a separate drive (could be [NAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage)) or partition for downloads. 
   Format as Fat32 if all your files are under 4gb. Format as exFAT if you might have files larger than 4gb. This should ensure all OS's are able to read and write to the directory.
3. VMware. I like the ability to easily change between OS's and take snapshots. VirtualBox for free alternative, lacks some of the features of the paid VMware versions.